# Internet connectivity check - Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, internet-connection

So, I have been on this for much longer than anticipated as to first finding out about this function, whilst it works great for being offline (a lack of a wifi or ethernet based connection) it is very hazy when determining if connected to the internet.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702(v=vs.85).aspx

The example case would be if there is a log in screen you would typically find at any coffee shops or hotel, or worse yet if connected to a wifi network with no internet connection, it will give back a result of online?!

Now, the desired function of mine is to give a very reliable return of 3 cases, definitely online, definitely offline, diagnose the issue on network (if connected via ethernet or wifi with no internet connection, including but not limited to disconnected ethernet at switch, wan ethernet port disconnected, hotel wifi, public wifi with log in etc etc)

2 known error codes thrown as a result of being "offline completely" whereby there is not a ethernet cable plugged in, or any wireless connection active; the second being for being on any network but not having a live web connection.

**Now as to the problem**

I have fully functioning code, however with my large access database in case 3 as mentioned above, the forms or any function running at that freezes, from simply dragging around a print preview screen to typing, it will freeze.

This is just not feasible with many background functions working, such as searches or other timers and it will cause problems when end users attempt to use something that constantly (every 10 seconds) would hang. Now I have already thought of the approach of changing the timer to every 5 minutes say, but that defeats the object here as I am attempting to continually show users especially within areas of intermittent internet connections that they are no longer connected.

I have searched for amending the timeout period, but that vaguely resolves my problem, it maybe shaved 1 second at most on average across extensive testing. Currently leaving me on around 4-6 seconds of "Access is not responsive"

To be clear, using my request response method is working fine in both simple cases of definitely online (obtains a response from a web page) and offline (instant timeout).

How can I eradicate the .get from lagging access to a stand still, even in vba you cannot scroll up/down or try to amend anything unless outside the period of the timer (10 seconds) so it takes 4-6 seconds to process the "Diagnosis" case, outputting text as a small box on the form.

```
Public Function ConnectivityCheck(urlzzz) As Long

On Error GoTo err_handler:
Dim Resolve, Connect, Send, Receive As Integer
Dim RequestResponse As XMLHTTP60
Dim K As Integer
Dim Parameter1 As String
Dim Doc As DOMDocument60
Set RequestResponse = New XMLHTTP60

Set Doc = New DOMDocument60
Set RequestResponse = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    Resolve = 200     ' In Milliseconds, 4 Stages to a Request.statement each individually attuned timing before
    Connect = 350    '"timing" out/cancelling the request.
    Send = 350
    Receive = 350     'waiting time to receive data from server
    RequestResponse.setTimeouts Resolve, Connect, Send, Receive

With RequestResponse
    .Open "GET", urlzzz, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .Send
    Doc.LoadXML .responseText
End With
Doc.LoadXML Doc.Text

If InStr(RequestResponse.responseText, "example") Then
    K = 1
    ConnectivityCheck = K
    Debug.Print RequestResponse.responseText

End If


Exit Function
err_handler:
    ConnectivityCheck = err.Number
    Debug.Print ConnectivityCheck
    If err.Number = -2147012894 Then
        Debug.Print "No internet connection" ' connected to some sort of network but no live web connection
    ElseIf err.Number = -2147012889 Then
    Debug.Print "Offline" 'simply unplugged or not connected to any wireless network
    End If
End Function

Public Sub testerrrr()
Dim urlzzz As String
urlzzz = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=example"
ConnectivityCheck (urlzzz)

End Sub
```

I appreciate any tips or pointers, even something basic I may have overlooked.

Thanks.

Comment: Access is not mutithread, so, you won't be able to eliminate freezing in the same application. As an idea: move checking code to separate accdb, store current status in table of this accdb and check status / call this function using Access object

Comment: @SergeyS.   Is there anyway to keep that as a background process (application) running without any disruption to the current access session? i.e most importantly its minimised, does not pop infront of the current access db. If I can make it not show up as a tab even better

Comment: Yes, you can hide the background application window and even task bar icon, so the process will be completely invisible for users